# onClick (mis)fired for previously displayed View?

Tags: android

I have two fragments:

- 1st fragment consists of a large button in the middle - I set an `OnClickListener` (programmatically) for this View, which replaces the 1st fragment with the 2nd once clicked.
- 2nd fragment is an empty fragment

At first, I display fragment no. 1. I then press the button and as expected, I get to see the 2nd fragment.

The problem: Once the 2nd fragment is displayed and I click in the middle of it - it fires the code behind the `OnClickListener` of the button in the **1st fragment**, even though I'm currently displaying an EMPTY FRAGMENT with no buttons at all.

Ideas?

Here's the code:

```
public void onLargeButtonClick(View view){
        secondFragment fragment = new secondFragment();
        fragmentFactory.replaceFragment(fragment);
}

void replaceFragment(Fragment fragment){
    FragmentManager fragmentManager = activity.getSupportFragmentManager();
    String fragmentName = fragment.getClass().getSimpleName();
    Fragment existingFragment = fragmentManager.findFragmentByTag(fragmentName);
    if (existingFragment != null)
        fragmentManager.popBackStack(fragmentName, FragmentManager.POP_BACK_STACK_INCLUSIVE);

        FragmentTransaction ft = activity.getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
        ft.setTransition(FragmentTransaction.TRANSIT_FRAGMENT_OPEN);
        ft.replace(R.id.first_fragment, fragment);
        ft.addToBackStack(null);
        ft.commit();
}
```

and the main layout contains the fragment which I replace

```
   <fragment
            android:name="com.app.firstfragment"
            android:id="@+id/first_fragment"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            >
    </fragment>
```

Comment: post the code of OnClick(...). to see how do you hide and show the fragments

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not really a good answer as to why this is happening, but I have similar things happening in my app. Couple of things you can try (or make sure):

- Remove the first fragment with the FragmentManager
- Remove the `OnClickListener` of the button in the onPause of the first fragment

Comment: onPause doesn't get fired for this fragment, any ideas?

Comment: Are you sue the code in "if (existingFragment != null)" is being called ? Seems like your check is not correct...

Answer (score 0):

You can make your new empty fragment clickable, by setting one of the root layout elements to `android:clickable="true"`.

This will intercept clicks on it, and prevent them from reaching a fragment below it.

Answer (score 0):

i think you cant cant replace fragment added in xml.

first remove `android:name="com.app.firstfragment"`

then add the first fragment by code in your activity

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            Fragment firstFragment = new firstFragment();
            FragmentTransaction ft = getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
            ft.add(R.id.first_fragment, firstFragment).commit();
    }
```

Comment: Thats impossible as I won't be able to inflate my view by the xml - the fragment object will be missing the name attribute